# iPhone 5 New iCloud address, but still have iMessage from previous iCloud

Tags: iphone, icloud, messages

I made a new iCloud address, but when I checked my iMessage, it had messages from my old iCloud. Do I have to manually delete these messages? 
Also, would my content in my iMessage app then be connected to my new iCloud address? Since I have synced the new one to my current phone

Answer (score 1):

I've done it myself. The only way to erase all messages was one by one.

The good part is that only new messages were synced!

Answer (score 0):

You're probably still signed into iMessage with your old iCloud account. Go to Settings->Messages->Send & Receive and then tap your Apple ID and tap Sign Out. Also uncheck your old Apple ID in the "You Can Be Reached By iMessage At" pane. Finally, sign back into iMessage with your new Apple ID  where you signed out of your old Apple ID.